# Pattern matching on a list of tuples

Tags: f#

I am attempting to create a function to pattern match a structure which is a tuple containing a value and a list of tuples of the form

```
'a * ('b * 'c) list -> 'b list
```

for example given the following:

```
let clubDetails = ("MyClub", [("Secretary", "Jill");("Captain", "Bob");("Email", "Bob@MyClub.com")])
```

I need a function to return the list ["Secretary";"Captain";"Email"]

So I thought I could do something like this :

```
let getClubAttributes ca = 
        match ca with
        | (a, [(b,c)]) -> [b]
        | _ -> []
```

but here

```
getClubAttributes clubDetails
```

Returns the empty list. I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious.

Thanks,
Russell.

Comment: yeah, your match list only with one value

Comment: I mean, you get the `["Secretary"]` if your list is will be something like that - `("MyClub", [("Secretary", "Jill")])`

Comment: so, you want to write `let getClubAttributes = snd >> List.map fst`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ecyQfz

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now.

Comment: glad to help, you should join to the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) - it's awesome place for learn F#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern match form that you have written will only match if the `list` in your tuple has *exactly* one element.

I note that you have written a default `_` case in your pattern match which returns the empty list and this is the case you are hitting.  I suspect you've added this case to remove the compiler warning but the compiler warning is, in fact, warning you of this exact problem.

You do not actually need a pattern match because your data structure can be handled with only one case.

```
let clubDetails = ("MyClub", [("Secretary", "Jill");("Captain", "Bob");("Email", "Bob@MyClub.com")])

let getClubAttributes (ca, attribList) =
    List.map fst attribList
```

The new `getClubAttributes` function simply creates a new list from the original by taking the first element of each item in the list.